# SQL query to change WooCommerce product variations tax

Tags: sql, wordpress, woocommerce, product-variations

I have a problem with a woocommerce store. Random products have ended up with the variation tax value set as 'standard' which is overriding the products actual tax class setting of 'zero-rate'.

To resolve this all that needs to be done is for the _tax_class values of the product variations (not the parent products) to be set to 'parent'. Once this is done woocommerce will default the _tax_class of the product itself.

So far I've created the following script to enable me to manually amend the tax classes from within PHPMyAdmin, however, I'm unable to edit any values because of the error mentioned below the query.

```
SELECT wp_postmeta.* , wp_posts.post_type, wp_posts.post_title, wp_posts.ID

FROM wp_postmeta INNER JOIN wp_posts  

ON wp_posts.id = wp_postmeta.post_id

WHERE wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_tax_class' AND wp_posts.post_type = 'product_variation'
```

Error message;

`'Current selection does not contain a unique column. Grid edit, checkbox, Edit, Copy and Delete features are not available'`

I've believe this may be an indexing issue due to the large database size (300mb uncompressed) but ive been unable to get it to see the primary key of either tables.

Any help or pointers would be great!!

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a pure SQL query to update all your product variations Tax class to a **`'parent'`** value:

```
UPDATE `wp_postmeta`
SET `meta_value` = 'parent'
WHERE `meta_key` LIKE '_tax_class'
  AND `post_id` IN
    (SELECT `ID`
     FROM `wp_posts`
     WHERE `post_type` = 'product_variation');
```

This is tested and works

> But… before running this query you should do a database backup